# How to get a dataframe name as a string in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame named 'data_by_month'

Here is a dummy data:

```
data = {'date' : ['1', '2','3'],
         'value1' : ['a', 'b' ,'c'],
         'value2' : ['12','24','4']}
data_by_month = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, as I work with this DataFrame, because I have other DataFrames to use alternatively (data_by_week or data_by_year), I defined another name for this DataFrame and use the new name throughout the work process, so I can just change the name once instead of changing all the names redundantly:

```
new_name = data_by_month
```

However, I don't know how I can get the DataFrame name as a string, 'data_by_month' in this case, regardless of which DataFrame is given.

Comment: sounds like a case of mixing data and names. Use a container for the dataframes, such as a list or dict instead, and use that to access the dataframes if you really want to.

Comment: so, if I use a list as a container, then I can get the names as string?

Comment: After you do `new_name=data_by_month`, both variables refer to the same object.  In Python an object does not have a name, so you can't change it.  Later you could do `new_name=data_by_year`, and `new_name` will reference a different object (dataframe).  Edit the script file if you don't like the names you used at various points; don't try to do anything fancy to make changes at runtime.